Failed to initialize all required WMI classes
On my Windows 10 Education
Launch the WMI MMC snapin by Start -> Run -> then enter WMIMGMT.MSC
Right-click WMI Control (Local) and click Properties
Following this link:
https://www.virtuallyboring.com/microsoft-wmi-invalid-class-error-0x80041010/
It showed:
Failed to initialize all required WMI classes.
Win32_Processor: WMI: Invalid class
Win32_WMISetting: WMI: Invalid class
Security information: Successful Win32_OperatingSystem: WMI Invalid class
**To Solved  **
I try in several ways.
First way
I ran the commands given below from the Admin command prompt to reset WMI components
From the command prompt navigate to C:>windows\system32\wbem
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\scecli.dll
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\userenv.dll
regsvr32 cimwin32.dll
mofcomp cimwin32.mof
mofcomp cimwin32.mfl
mofcomp rsop.mof
mofcomp rsop.mfl
for /f %s in ('dir /b /s *.dll') do regsvr32 /s %s
for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mof') do mofcomp %s
for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mfl') do mofcomp %s
regsvr32 wmisvc.dll
wmiprvse /regserver
Second way
From the command prompt navigate to C:>windows\system32\wbem
I ran the below command and it worked.
WinMgmt /?
When I tried to run Meteor Project it showed the error.
Error starting Mongo (2 tries left): Couldn't run tasklist.exe: {"killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"cmd":"tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq mongod.exe""}
